# How to get country name from country code?

Tags: magento

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('custom/table')->getCollection();
```

I have one custom table and there is one field country_code.

Now I am passing this $collection to my javascript and using variables in that.

Now I want to display country name instead of country code.

Is there any way from which I can add country name in my collection using join query or any way else ?

so before passing to js I want country name in my collection object.

Comment: Any chance you can offer more information about these tables and where you are storing country name?

Comment: If you are getting country code like 'IN/USA/UK..." this code may usefull            $countryName = Mage::getModel(’directory/country’)->load($country_id)->getName();

Comment: if you find my answer helpful then accept my answer

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Magento stores the country names in locale files so that you can change the country name based on your language.

If you have the country code and you want to get the country name use the below code:

```
$country_name=Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslation($country_code);
```

Or you can also try

```
// $countryCode looks like "US"
$country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode($countryCode);
echo $country->getName(); /
```

Please let me know if i can help you more.

Answer (score 2):

you can get country name from

```
$countryModel = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode('country_code');

$countryName = $countryModel->getName();
```

Answer (score 2):

echo *`Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode($address->getCountry_id())->getName();`*
Where **`$address->getCountry_id()`** replace with country id .

Answer (score 1):

For Magento2, you need to do the following in order to get Country name from the codebook:

1. First, instantiate Country model:

> $this->countryHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Magento\Directory\Model\Country');

2. Then make a custom method to retrieve name of the Country by supplying ISO CC:

> final function getCountryName($iso = null, $locale = null){
>
> $theEarthIsFlat = $this->countryHelper->loadByCode($iso);
>
> return $theEarthIsFlat->getName($locale);
>   }

3. Usage example:

> $_countryCode = $this->getData('country_id');
>
> $_countryName = $this->getVendorCountryName($_countryCode);

Comment: Direct use of Object Manager is discouraged, instead you should instantiate it in class constructor.